# I'm trying to replicate the devconnector project but when I make post request a profile route create profile the post request is pending

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express

this is the route:

```js
router.post(
      '/',
      [  auth,
        check('status', 'Status is required').not().isEmpty(),
        check('skills', 'Skills is required').not().isEmpty(),
      ],
      async (req, res) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
          return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
        }
    
        // destructure the request
        const {
          website,
          skills,
          youtube,
          twitter,
          instagram,
          linkedin,
          facebook,
          // spread the rest of the fields we don't need to check
          ...rest
        } = req.body;
    
        // build a profile
        const profileFields = {
          user: req.user.id,
          website:
            website && website !== ''
              ? normalize(website, { forceHttps: true })
              : '',
          skills: Array.isArray(skills)
            ? skills
            : skills.split(',').map((skill) => ' ' + skill.trim()),
          ...rest
        };
    
        // Build socialFields object
        const socialFields = { youtube, twitter, instagram, linkedin, facebook };
    
        // normalize social fields to ensure valid url
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(socialFields)) {
          if (value && value.length > 0)
            socialFields[key] = normalize(value, { forceHttps: true });
        }
        // add to profileFields
        profileFields.social = socialFields;
    
        try {
          // Using upsert option (creates new doc if no match is found):
          let profile = await Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
            { user: req.user.id },
            { $set: profileFields },
            { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true }
          );
          return res.json(profile);
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
          return res.status(500).send('Server Error');
        }
      }
    );
```

this is Axios:

```
                   axios.post('/api/profile',profileData, {headers:{
            'x-auth-token': localStorage.getItem('jwtToken')
          }}).then(data => console.log(data)).catch(e => console.error(e))
```

this is problem:
[pending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWLv2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use debugger in order to follow software flow?
Have you any log from express side?
I'd start checking if `let profile = await Profile.findOneAndUpdate` is reached in order to define if the problem starts on db request.
At this stage I would say that the execution is pending waiting for db timeout